# Tracking external contribution sources

Tags: tracked-links

Is it possible in CiviContribute to track multiple **external (non-CiviCRM)** sources of contributions to a single form?

I've used other systems where I could create a source code for, say, a banner ad and apply that source code to the donation form URL. I could then create another source code for donation links within an email. Sometime later, I'd be able to pull up a donation report for that form and see that there were X number of donations that came in from the banner ad, and X number from the email.

Answer (score 1):

What we have done is to add 3 custom fields to the contribution (utm_source, utm_media and utm_campaign) that store the tracking codes, the same way google analytics work.

To make it more automatic, we have an extension that does automatically adds these codes to all the links sent from civimail, so we have end to end tracking.

We haven't yet published this extension in civicrm.org, but you can fetch it from our github repository.
https://github.com/WeMoveEU/utmaltor

Comment: Nice. Nice. Nice

Comment: Thanks very much, Xavier. We'll be using MailChimp, however, not CiviMail.  But I'll take a look at your extension. I'll be away from this project next week, but I'll post again the following week and let you know how it goes.

Appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, Xavier. Still haven't gotten back to this, but hope to soon. Thanks again.